# Change Safari URL with App Extension

Tags: ios, swift, safari, ios-app-extension

When the icon of my Safari app extension icon is touched, I want to change the URL without showing a new view. Doing this comes down to two issues:

- How can I use an safari app extension without showing a new view? I just want to perform a background action when the extension icon is pressed.
- How can I change the current URL in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you might be able to change the URL at the finalize function of your ExtensionPreprocessingJS file

```
   // Note that the finalize function is only available in iOS.
   finalize: function(arguments) {

   // arguments contains the value the extension provides in   
   [NSExtensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:completion:].

   // In this example, the extension provides a color as a returning item.
   document.URL = arguments["newUrl"];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're describing is a bookmark, and not an app extension. I would highly doubt that app extensions would allow you to interface with Safari and update the URL, this would be wrong in many regards, including privacy and security. In short, **not possible** (sorry).